# Hide subtitle track or audio track on the AirPlay device

Tags: ios, avplayer, airplay

I have a HLS manifest with multiple audio and multiple subtitle tracks. I use AVPlayer on iOS to play this HLS asset.

On the iOS app I have the freedom to display selective subtitle and audio track list to the user but when the user uses AirPlay on the iOS, all the subtitle and audio tracks available in the HLS manifest is displayed to the user on the Apple TV (or any AirPlay compatible device).

Let me explain with one example.

Say, the HLS manifest has the following tracks:

- English, Spanish & German audio tracks
- English, Italian, Spanish & German subtitle tracks

When the user uses AirPlay, I want to **hide German** language and display only the following tracks on the Apple TV:

- English & Spanish audio tracks
- English, Italian & Spanish subtitle tracks

The primary intent here is that the user should not be able to see German language anywhere on the target AirPlay device.

How to achieve this in code?

Note: It's difficult to modify the source HLS manifest file.